# Problem connecting CloudRun, and LoadBalancer and IAP with a custom domain on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to put a **cloudrun** behind a **load balancer** to use the **IAP authentication**, I created a custom domain on [domains.google.com](https://domains.google.com/), but for some reason, I cannot seem to have access to my cloudrun on the domain.
I ran the terraform successfully.
I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-lb-http/blob/0da99a24fdaf4c4163039efa52243a500b604d1e/examples/cloudrun/main.tf) skipping the CloudRun creation in Terraform as I already configured it with a cloudbuild.

**Here is the Terraform:**

**version.tf**

```ccl
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.11.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.11.0"
    }
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

```hcl
################################################################
#                                                              #
#                                                              #
#                Create VPC access connector                   #
#                                                              #
#                                                              #
################################################################

resource "google_vpc_access_connector" "connector" {
  name          = "vpc-connector"
  region        = var.region
  project       = var.project
  ip_cidr_range = "10.8.0.0/28"
  network       = "default"
}


################################################################
#                                                              #
#                                                              #
#              Create network ednpoint group                   #
#                                                              #
#                                                              #
################################################################

resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "serverless_neg" {
  name                  = "serverless-neg"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = var.region
  cloud_run {
    service = local.run_service_name
  }
}


module "lb-http" {
  source  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/lb-http/google//modules/serverless_negs"
  version = "~> 6.2.0"

  project = var.project
  name    = var.lb_name

  ssl                             = true
  managed_ssl_certificate_domains = ["ooshotnotiontoolbox.com"]
  https_redirect                  = true

  backends = {
    default = {
      description = null
      groups = [
        {
          group = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.serverless_neg.id
        }
      ]
      enable_cdn              = false
      security_policy         = null
      custom_request_headers  = null
      custom_response_headers = null

      iap_config = {
        enable               = true
        oauth2_client_id     = "iap-client-id"
        oauth2_client_secret = var.iap_client_secret
      }
      log_config = {
        enable      = false
        sample_rate = null
      }
    }
  }
}

data "google_iam_policy" "iap" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor"
    members = [
      "domain:my-domain.com",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_iap_web_backend_service_iam_policy" "policy" {
  project             = var.project
  web_backend_service = "${var.lb_name}-backend-default"
  policy_data         = data.google_iam_policy.iap.policy_data
  depends_on = [
    module.lb-http
  ]
}

output "load-balancer-ip" {
  value = module.lb-http.external_ip
}

output "oauth2-redirect-uri" {
  value = "https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/oauth/clientIds/${var.iap_client_id}:handleRedirect"
}
```

**And the cloudbuild.yaml**:

```sh
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:$SHORT_SHA', '.' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:$SHORT_SHA']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
    - 'run'
    - 'deploy'
    - '${_SERVICE_NAME}'
    - '--region=${_REGION}'
    - '--platform=managed'
    - '--allow-unauthenticated'
    - '--ingress=internal-and-cloud-load-balancing'
    - '--vpc-connector=vpc-connector'
    - '--memory=1024Mi'
    - '--service-account=${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    - '--image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:$SHORT_SHA'
    - '--set-env-vars=PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

The DNS records:

```json
GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1beta2/projects/notion-integration-dv/managedZones/ooshotnotiontoolbox-com
{
  "cloudLoggingConfig": {},
  "creationTime": "2022-03-21T21:43:02.173Z",
  "description": "DNS zone for domain: ooshotnotiontoolbox.com",
  "dnsName": "ooshotnotiontoolbox.com.",
  "dnssecConfig": {
    "state": "ON",
    "defaultKeySpecs": [
      {
        "keyType": "KEY_SIGNING",
        "algorithm": "RSASHA256",
        "keyLength": 2048
      },
      {
        "keyType": "ZONE_SIGNING",
        "algorithm": "RSASHA256",
        "keyLength": 1024
      }
    ],
    "nonExistence": "NSEC3"
  },
  "fingerprint": "2d297a1a7d2348c50000017fae6ef71d",
  "id": "3254266459939096773",
  "name": "ooshotnotiontoolbox-com",
  "nameServers": [
    "ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com."
  ],
  "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
```

A rule to add the Loadbalancer's IP address

```json
{
  "name": "*.ooshotnotiontoolbox.com.",
  "rrdata": [
    "34.118.230.189"
  ],
  "ttl": 300,
  "type": "A"
}
```

Load Balancer Certificate won't provision

```json
{
  "creationTimestamp": "2022-03-21T14:50:38.853-07:00",
  "description": "",
  "id": "774651587549547969",
  "kind": "compute#sslCertificate",
  "managed": {
    "status": "PROVISIONING",
    "domains": [
      "ooshotnotiontoolbox.com"
    ],
    "domainStatus": {
      "ooshotnotiontoolbox.com": "FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE"
    }
  },
  "name": "ooshotnotiontoolbox-com-cert",
  "selfLink": "projects/notion-integration-dv/global/sslCertificates/ooshotnotiontoolbox-com-cert",
  "type": "MANAGED"
}
```

**The errors**:

1. When I go to the **https://project-name.a.run.app**:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Access is forbidden.</h2>
<h2></h2>

</body></html>
```

2. When I go to the domain name I bought **https://ooshotnotiontoolbox.com**:
   `Safari Can’t Find the Server`
3. In the Load Balancer configuration, under Certificate details
   [image: Load Balancer config image]

Comment: What is the problem and the error? Is this a connection issue or a configuration failure? Just showing the configuration files is not enough.

Comment: @JohnHanley info added it is a connection issue, but I think it comes from a problem in the configuration

Comment: Your DNS server is not configured correctly. That is why the certificate is not provisioning.   Edit your question and include the DNS resource records you created for the load balancer.

Comment: That DNS resource record is not part of the domain's **authoritative** DNS name server. Did you create another DNS server? If yes, you must change the NS records to point to the new DNS server. Your current name server is `ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com` Which one did you create records at?

Comment: @JohnHanley, you wer right, I had multiple DNS resolvers, It has been fixed, unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the certificate from the load balancer, maybe there is an extra step I am missing

Comment: Since you had a DNS problem, you can either wait or delete the current certificate request and issue a new one.